# How to combine (results) of multiple pytorch models?

Tags: python, pytorch, yolov5

community,

in pytorch (& yolov5) i was able to train two models (one detects cars, the other detects bikes).

I am loading two different models (last.pt files) with the following commands:

```
model_c = torch.hub.load('ultralytics/yolov5', 'custom', path='/last.pt', force_reload=True)
model_b = torch.hub.load('ultralytics/yolov5', 'custom', path='/last.pt', force_reload=True)
```

I use an image for the model to detect cars or bikes in:

```
img = os.path.join('data', 'images', 'traffic.jpg')
```

The results command can show the model detection for cars:

```
results = model_c(img)
results.print()
```

..**or** bikes:

```
results = model_b(img)
results.print()
```

Question 1:

**How can the results of cars and bikes detections be shown in the same image at the same time?**

Question 2:

**Is there a way to combine two model pt.files into one?**

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Create a class to combine models?